# Kendo UI List View not displaying data

Tags: kendo-ui

I Use a kendo UI list view. But even though I use a datasource, I don't see any data in the list view.

Can anybody help me out?

**Here is my code,**

*Created a div #listView and a template .Then trying to bind data to the list view*

```
<div id="listView"></div>
```

**And this is the template i use**

*Template created using Kendo UI*

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template" >
    <div class="product">     
        <h3>#:title#</h3>
        <p>#:kendo.toString(year, "c")#</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

**here i bind the datasource**

*This doesnt work although i bind the data.Is there any other way of binding data*

```
var dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            dataType: "json",
            data: [
                { title: "Star Wars: A New Hope", year: 1977 }, 
                { title: "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980}
            ]  
        }
    }
});

$("#listView").kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSource1,
    template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are binding your listview to local data, there is no need to call a transport... Just bind the data directly to the datasource :

```
var dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { title: "Star Wars: A New Hope", year: 1977 }, 
        { title: "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980}
    ]  
});
```

You can have a look to the demo page of a datasource here : http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/index.html.

PS : by the way, the format "c", is for currency (see the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting)). Here you can call directly the year in your template : `#:year#`.